# Getting error in LINQ query to sqlite

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, xamarin

I'm trying to make login query in sqlite but can't convert `AsyncTableQuery` in `boolean`

```
public bool queryLogIn(string userNameLogIn,string passwordLogIn)
{
    var query=database.Table<Users>().Where(i => i.UserName == userNameLogIn && i.Password == passwordLogIn);

    if (query == true)//There is error
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }                
}
```

Comment: Hi. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer. Check this link to know How does accepting an answer work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

`Where` returns an `iqueryable` of `Users`. You need [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) instead which *Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition* and since it's return type is bool you can use it in your `if` statement:

```
var query=database.Table<Users>().Any(i => i.UserName == userNameLogIn
                                           && i.Password == passwordLogIn);
```

**EDIT**: Or use `Any` in your `if`:

```
var query=database.Table<Users>().Where(i => i.UserName == userNameLogIn 
                                             && i.Password == passwordLogIn);
if (query.Any())
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: how to that query ?

Comment: I'm sorry there is no .Any(). I can do query.CountAsyn() , .toListAsync() , .take() , .skip() ,.equals()... but no .Any().
However thank you very much

Comment: @KosovoDev What about `.toListAsync().Any()` ?

Comment: @KosovoDev are you sure that you've added `using System.Linq;` to your using directives?

Comment: Yes but no Any() method

Answer (score 1):

You can use FirstOrDefault function for login is success.

```
public bool queryLogIn(string userNameLogIn,string passwordLogIn)
{
var query=database.Table<Users>().FirstOrDefault(i => i.UserName == userNameLogIn && i.Password == passwordLogIn);

if (query == null)//There is error
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}                
}
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault has no argument